# How to pass custom string in JavaScript function from code behind in?

Tags: javascript, c#, c#-4.0

I have a string structure like this:

```
    string str = "[['<h1>Heading 1</h1><p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p><p>Paragraph 3</p>', 31, 32,1],
['<h1>Heading 1</h1><p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p><p>Paragraph 3</p>', 34, 35,2]]";
```

I am trying to pass this string in javascript function but alert is not working. How can I pass this string in JS function. So far I have tried this but it is not working

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "test", "test('" + str + "')", true);
```

JS

```
 function test(str) {

    alert(str);
 }
```

Comment: Check the generated javascript, it contains embedded quotes that end the string prematurely. You will need to escape (at least) the quotes.

Comment: @HansKesting string has proper quotes I have already checked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the generated javascript, it will start with `test('[['` - and then the rest is not recognised as string content and gives a javascript error.

You will need to escape the string, using [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "test",
 "test('" + HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(str) + "')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use native browser JSON stringify function.. like this..

```
function test(str){
    alert( JSON.stringify( str ) ) ;
}
```

you should get your array in popup..

hth